# Cypress - click hyperlink on row based on value of two cells

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

Trying to get a Cypress script to click a hyperlink based on two values - the text of the hyperlink in column 1 and the value of the cell in the second column:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/id/343408">Anything</a></td>
    <td>Casualty</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/id/338494">Declined Prospect</a></td>
    <td>Casualty</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/id/343408">Declined Prospect</a></td>
    <td>Package</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/id/338494">Declined Prospect</a></td>
    <td>Casualty</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/id/338432">Irrelevant</a></td>
    <td>Package</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**cy.get('a').contains('Declined Prospect').click()**

fails because there's more than one hyperlink with that value. The id is not useful because it's dynamic.

In the example above, I want to click **Declined Prospect** when the second column is **Casualty** (but the order of the rows may vary and values in the first and second column are repeated - but only once for the combination).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to target `<td>Casualty</td>` then click the preceding `<td><a>`.

There are quite a few ways to get to sibling elements, the simplest in this case is [prev()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/prev.html#Examples).

```js
cy.contains('td', 'Casualty')  // target the 'marker' element
  .prev()                      // move to the previous sibling
  .click()
```

---

**Approach from row and move inwards**

To target a row with a specific combination of text in some of it's cells, just concatenate the text and use `contains()`.

```js
cy.contains('tr', 'Declined Prospect Casualty')  // target unique text within children
```

This even works when there are other cells with text that's not relevent to the search, e.g

```html
<tr>
  <td><a href="/id/338494">Declined Prospect</a></td>
  <td>Casualty</td>
  <td>Irrelevent text here</td>
</tr>
```

Then you can walk down the HTML tree,

```js
cy.contains('tr', 'Declined Prospect Casualty') // target unique text within children
  .find('td a')                                 // descendant of previous subject
  .click()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there could be many instances of Casualty in the second column that precede this one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be useful: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath

You can create selectors in xpath instead of css and in xpath you can search tree by text. e.g:

```
cy.xpath("//text() = 'Declined Prospect'")
```

==================================Edited====================
You can merge couples of xpatch selectors: it will looks like this `//tr[td='Casualty']/td/a`

[Playgroud](https://xpath.playground.fontoxml.com/?mode=0&variables=%7B%7D&xml=%3Ctbody%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Fid%2F343408%22%3EDeclined%20Prospect%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EPackage%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Fid%2F338494%22%3EDeclined%20Prospect%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3ECasualty%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2Fid%2F338432%22%3EIrrelevant%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3EPackage%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%3C%2Ftbody%3E&xpath=%2F%2Ftr%5Btd%3D%27Casualty%27%5D%2Ftd%2Fa%0A&context=)

Comment: Hmm... that finds the first Declined Prospect. How would I click Declined Prospect when the second cell is Casualty?